# exception handling in MIT scheme

Tags: exception, scheme, mit-scheme

How do I raise and handle an exception in MIT scheme?

Something like [it doesn't work]

```
((< val 0) (raise "-ve value") )
```

Answer (score 3):

The documentation does provide the answer, but no code samples, so here is one:

```
(define (handler x)
    (display "Handling Error: ")(display x)(newline)
    (restart 1))
```

Here we're just displaying the error (what the documentation calls a "condition")
and doing nothing.

To have this function handle all conditions do:

```
(bind-default-condition-handler '() handler)
```

Or you can just wrap one code block with:

```
(bind-condition-handler '() handler (3 4))
```

Comment: dkinzer, the code was purposefully wrong, so that an exception would get handled.

Answer (score 1):

As dvingo pointed out, the docs do not show any example so here is another example that uses the "error" built-in special form (at least in MIT-scheme):

```
(define (errors-if-zero x)
  (if (= x 0)
    (error "x is 0")
    x))
```