# Detect if file can be opened in Scheme

Tags: file, io, scheme, mit-scheme

I am currently working on a project where I am reading in contents from a file, line by line. I would like to check if the file can be opened or is present before I do this. Something like checking the return contents of fopen() in C++, but in Scheme.

Thus far I have:

```
(define (perform action fileName . args) 
    (if (file-exists? fileName)
        ((define in-file (open-input-file fileName))
        (do ((line (read-line in-file) (read-line in-file))) ((eof-object? line))
            (display line)
            (newline)))

        (map display
            (list "Unable to open " fileName " for reading\n"))
    ) 
)
```

All this code does however is read in the file, line by line and attempts to check if the file exists. It however doesn't work because I get a ";Can't bind name in null syntactic environment: in-file #[reserved-name-item 13]" error.

I realize when the file is unable to be opened, an error of type condition-type:file-operation-error is signalled as per [MIT Scheme Documentation](https://groups.csail.mit.edu/mac/ftpdir/scheme-7.4/doc-html/scheme_15.html#SEC131); However, I am unable to figure out how to handle this exception, thus my workaround.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you read the section on condition handling?

Comment: https://groups.csail.mit.edu/mac/ftpdir/scheme-7.4/doc-html/scheme_toc.html#TOC156

Comment: You could also simply use `(if (file-exists? fileName) ...)`

Comment: I did read the section on conditional handling. I was confused as to how to integrate that into the code I have as no examples are really given. Thank you for the last suggestion, I will try it!

Comment: There are some examples here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968524/exception-handling-in-mit-scheme

Comment: I attempted the file-exists solution, however it now gives me an error. I have updated question with my new code as well as the error I receive.

Comment: `if` can only take one expression for each arm; either wrap multiple expressions in a `begin` form, or use `cond` which _does_ accept multiple expressions in each conditional clause.

Comment: And, there are extra parentheses around `((define in-file (open-input-file fileName))`, And, you can only place `define` at the top level or at the top of a body. You need to get the basics of Scheme down before you start attempting I/O operations.

Comment: Use `let` to bind a local variable, not `define`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have one issue with the code. You can't randomly add parenthesis into the code to make single expression for `if`, because parentheses are function calls. To make single expression you need to use begin:

```lisp
(define (perform action fileName . args) 
    (if (file-exists? fileName)
        (begin
          (define in-file (open-input-file fileName))
          (do ((line (read-line in-file) (read-line in-file))) ((eof-object? line))
              (display line)
              (newline)))
        (map display
            (list "Unable to open " fileName " for reading\n"))
    )
)
```